# Website tells me my query has a reserved word, although it works in access

Tags: asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010

The exact error is "The SELECT statement includes a reserved word or an argument name that is misspelled or missing, or the punctuation is incorrect."

Here's the query it has to be referring to, since it happened after I added it.

```
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource3" runat="server" 
        DataFile="~/App_Data/TravelJoansDB.accdb" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT TOP 5 FROM Table2 ORDER BY RND([ID])" />

<asp:DataList ID="Datalist3" runat="server" 
            DataSourceID="AccessDataSource3" 
            DataKeyField="ID" 
            RepeatColumns="5" 
            RepeatDirection="Horizontal" 
            GridLines="Both" 
            ItemStyle-CssClass="picRandomStyle">
                <ItemStyle />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Image ID="RandomImage" runat="server" AlternateText="Another Blog Post" 
                                ImageUrl='<%# "PlaceImages/" + Eval("Image") %>' 
                                Width="150" Height="135px" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <hr />
                                <asp:Label ID="RandomLabel" runat="server" CssClass="picTitleStyle" Text='<%# Eval("BlogTitle") %>' />
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try: SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Table2 ORDER BY RND([ID])

Comment: I'll mark it as the answer in 5 minutes, apparently... I hate it when I miss something so goofy as that...